# TableView navigates to the last row cell after commit edit when using extractor for TableView ObservableList

Tags: java, javafx, tableview, extractor

I have a TableView of Bean type that consists of name, quantity, price, and total price columns. These columns have the ability to be changed using TextFieldTableCell except the total column which is responsible for representing total cost of each row. Also, I have defined an extractor to observe price and quantity properties changes. Here is some piece of code:

```
public void start(Stage primaryStage) {
        TableView<Bean> table = new TableView<>();
        table.setEditable(true);
        table.getSelectionModel().setCellSelectionEnabled(true);

        TableColumn<Bean, String> nameColumn = new TableColumn<>("name");
        nameColumn.setCellValueFactory(new PropertyValueFactory<>("name"));
        nameColumn.setCellFactory(TextFieldTableCell.forTableColumn());
        nameColumn.setOnEditCommit(e -> {
            Bean bean = e.getRowValue();
            bean.setName(e.getNewValue());
        });

        TableColumn<Bean, Integer> quantityColumn = new TableColumn<>("quantity");
        quantityColumn.setCellValueFactory(new PropertyValueFactory<>("quantity"));
        quantityColumn.setCellFactory(TextFieldTableCell.forTableColumn(new StringConverter<>() {
            @Override
            public String toString(Integer object) {
                return object.toString();
            }

            @Override
            public Integer fromString(String string) {
                return Integer.parseInt(string);
            }
        }));
        quantityColumn.setOnEditCommit(e -> {
            Bean bean = e.getRowValue();
            bean.setQuantity(e.getNewValue());
        });

        TableColumn<Bean, Integer> priceColumn = new TableColumn<>("price");
        priceColumn.setCellValueFactory(new PropertyValueFactory<>("price"));
        priceColumn.setCellFactory(TextFieldTableCell.forTableColumn(new StringConverter<>() {
            @Override
            public String toString(Integer object) {
                return object.toString();
            }

            @Override
            public Integer fromString(String string) {
                return Integer.parseInt(string);
            }
        }));
        quantityColumn.setOnEditCommit(e -> {
            Bean bean = e.getRowValue();
            bean.setQuantity(e.getNewValue());
        });

        TableColumn<Bean, Integer> totalColumn = new TableColumn<>("total");
        totalColumn.setCellValueFactory(new PropertyValueFactory<>("totalPrice"));

        table.getColumns().addAll(nameColumn, priceColumn, quantityColumn, totalColumn);

        ObservableList<Bean> list = FXCollections.observableArrayList(bean -> new Observable[]{bean.priceProperty(), bean.quantityProperty()});
        list.add(new Bean("Tomato", 20, 100));
        list.add(new Bean("Orange", 10, 200));

        table.setItems(list);

        BorderPane pane = new BorderPane();
        pane.setCenter(table);

        Scene scene = new Scene(pane);
        Stage stage = new Stage();
        stage.setScene(scene);
        stage.show();
    }



    public static void main(String[] args) {
        launch(args);
    }

public class Bean {
    private SimpleStringProperty name;
    private SimpleIntegerProperty quantity;
    private SimpleIntegerProperty price;
    private SimpleIntegerProperty totalPrice;

    Bean(String name, Integer quantity, Integer price) {
        this.name = new SimpleStringProperty(name);
        this.quantity = new SimpleIntegerProperty(quantity);
        this.price = new SimpleIntegerProperty(price);
        this.totalPrice = new SimpleIntegerProperty(0);
        this.totalPrice.bind(Bindings.createIntegerBinding(() -> {
            return getQuantity() * getPrice();
        }, quantityProperty(), priceProperty()));
    }

    public String getName() {
        return this.name.get();
    }

    public void setName(String name) {
        this.name.set(name);
    }

    public Integer getQuantity() {
        return this.quantity.get();
    }

    public void setQuantity(Integer quantity) {
        this.quantity.set(quantity);
    }

    public SimpleIntegerProperty quantityProperty() {
        return this.quantity;
    }

    public Integer getPrice() {
        return this.price.get();
    }

    public void setPrice(Integer price) {
        this.price.set(price);
    }

    public SimpleIntegerProperty priceProperty() {
        return this.price;
    }

    public Integer getTotalPrice() {
        return this.totalPrice.get();
    }

    public void setTotalPrice(Integer totalPrice) {
        this.totalPrice.set(totalPrice);
    }
}
```

The problem is every time I set an extractor for ObservableList, TableView navigates to the last cell of the current row after committing an edit on price or quantity column.

Comment: might be unrelated: no need for commit handlers

Comment: @kleopatra I have tasted it over and over and that's because of the extractor. When I remove the extractor, everything will be okay.

Comment: read my comment carefully (hint: I didn't talk about the extractor :)

Comment: @kleopatra I know but also, I get rid of commit handlers and nothing is changed. I am sure that something is wrong with the extractor but unfortunately it's not known to me. :(

Comment: your bean is a bit weird - you have properties in its api so why don't you use them as valueFactories? Expose totalPrice as ReadOnlyProperty, and no extractor needed. Base line: _prefere cellFactories build with ObservableValues over propertyValueFactory_ And don't forget to really remove the commit handlers :)

Comment: actually, I can reproduce the behavior - looks like a bug in selection when an extractor is involved

Comment: @kleopatra Thank you.  2 Years and 2 months later... Project has been finished long time ago. But thank you anyway :)

Comment: only got back here because this question was referenced in a recent one: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72919839/editable-tableview-navigates-to-last-cell-when-using-extractor-for-observable-li :) As noted there, the issue seems to be that selection model's listener to item changes doesn't handle changes of type wasUpdated (that's what's fired from the extractor) correctly, actually it simply ignores it .. Good that your project got got finished successfully, despite of this obstacle