# Editable TableView navigates to last cell when using extractor for observable list

Tags: java, javafx

I have a JavaFX table view with custom editable cells.
It contains fields for item name, quantity, price, discount, tax and amount.
Every field is editable using the setCellFactory method and an implementation of a class extended by TableCell class. And I also have an **extractor** on the observable list to detect changes in quantity and amount properties of the list to calculate total values for them. [My question is a duplicate of this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61583640/tableview-navigates-to-the-last-row-cell-after-commit-edit-when-using-extractor), but it wasn't answered there, so here I am asking it again.
So when I press on a field it starts editing but as I shift focus using the tab it navigates to the last column and after that, If I click on the cell again it starts editing for a millisecond and then again navigates to the last cell.
This problem is resolved when I remove the extractor but then I cannot detect changes in observable list properties.
It behaves weirdly because for some time it works OK and other times it doesn't.

[GIF Showing the problem](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Up6Fa.gif)

**Main Application**

```java
import javafx.application.Application;
import javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader;
import javafx.scene.Scene;
import javafx.stage.Stage;

import java.io.IOException;

public class HelloApplication extends Application {
    @Override
    public void start(Stage stage) throws IOException {
        FXMLLoader fxmlLoader = new FXMLLoader(HelloApplication.class.getResource("EditableTableView.fxml"));
        Scene scene = new Scene(fxmlLoader.load());
        stage.setScene(scene);
        stage.show();
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        launch();
    }
}
```

**View FXML Code**

```fxml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>

<?import javafx.scene.control.TableColumn?>
<?import javafx.scene.control.TableView?>

<TableView fx:id="transactionsTable" editable="true" maxHeight="1.7976931348623157E308" minHeight="-Infinity"
           minWidth="-Infinity" prefHeight="500.0" prefWidth="1200.0" tableMenuButtonVisible="true"
           xmlns="http://javafx.com/javafx/18" xmlns:fx="http://javafx.com/fxml/1"
           fx:controller="com.example.testingpurposejavafx.EditableTableViewController">
    <columns>
        <TableColumn fx:id="idCol" editable="false" prefWidth="50.66670632362366"/>
        <TableColumn fx:id="qtyCol" minWidth="0.0" prefWidth="50.0" text="quantity"/>
        <TableColumn fx:id="priceUnitCol" prefWidth="50.0" text="price unit"/>
        <TableColumn prefWidth="200.0" text="discount">
            <columns>
                <TableColumn fx:id="discountRateCol" prefWidth="150.0" text="rate"/>
                <TableColumn fx:id="discountAmountCol" prefWidth="150.0" text="amount"/>
            </columns>
        </TableColumn>
        <TableColumn prefWidth="200.0" text="tax">
            <columns>
                <TableColumn fx:id="taxRateCol" prefWidth="150.0" text="rate"/>
                <TableColumn fx:id="taxAmountCol" minWidth="0.0" prefWidth="150.0" text="amount"/>
            </columns>
        </TableColumn>
        <TableColumn fx:id="amountCol" prefWidth="50.0" text="amount"/>
    </columns>
    <columnResizePolicy>
        <TableView fx:constant="CONSTRAINED_RESIZE_POLICY"/>
    </columnResizePolicy>
</TableView>
```

**Table Model Class**

```java
package com.example.testingpurposejavafx;

import javafx.beans.property.*;

public class TransactionTable {

    private final IntegerProperty id = new SimpleIntegerProperty();

    private final StringProperty item = new SimpleStringProperty();

    private final StringProperty quantity = new SimpleStringProperty();

    private final StringProperty priceUnit = new SimpleStringProperty();

    private final StringProperty discountRate = new SimpleStringProperty();

    private final StringProperty discountAmount = new SimpleStringProperty();

    private final StringProperty taxRate = new SimpleStringProperty();

    private final StringProperty taxAmount = new SimpleStringProperty();

    private final StringProperty amount = new SimpleStringProperty();

  //Getter Setter and property fields skipped
}
```

**Main Controller Class**

```java
package com.example.testingpurposejavafx;

import javafx.beans.Observable;
import javafx.collections.FXCollections;
import javafx.collections.ObservableList;
import javafx.fxml.Initializable;
import javafx.scene.control.TableColumn;
import javafx.scene.control.TablePosition;
import javafx.scene.control.TableView;
import javafx.scene.input.KeyEvent;
import javafx.scene.input.MouseEvent;

import java.net.URL;
import java.util.ResourceBundle;

public class EditableTableViewController implements Initializable {

    public TableView<TransactionTable> transactionsTable;
    public TableColumn<TransactionTable, Number> idCol;
    public TableColumn<TransactionTable, String> qtyCol;
    public TableColumn<TransactionTable, String> priceUnitCol;
    public TableColumn<TransactionTable, String> discountRateCol;
    public TableColumn<TransactionTable, String> discountAmountCol;
    public TableColumn<TransactionTable, String> taxRateCol;
    public TableColumn<TransactionTable, String> taxAmountCol;
    public TableColumn<TransactionTable, String> amountCol;

    public final ObservableList<TransactionTable> transactionList = FXCollections.observableArrayList(transaction -> new Observable[]{transaction.quantityProperty(), transaction.amountProperty()});

    @Override
    public void initialize(URL location, ResourceBundle resources) {
        transactionsTable.setItems(transactionList);
transactionsTable.getSelectionModel().setCellSelectionEnabled(true);
        setCellValueFactory();
        setCellFactory();
        addRow();
    }

    private void addRow() {
        var transactionTable = new TransactionTable();
        transactionTable.setId(transactionsTable.getItems().isEmpty() ? 1 : transactionsTable.getItems().size() + 1);
        transactionList.add(transactionTable);
    }

    private void setCellFactory() {
        qtyCol.setCellFactory(param -> new TextEditingCell<>());
        priceUnitCol.setCellFactory(param -> new TextEditingCell<>());
        discountRateCol.setCellFactory(param -> new TextEditingCell<>());
        discountAmountCol.setCellFactory(param -> new TextEditingCell<>());
        taxRateCol.setCellFactory(param -> new TextEditingCell<>());
        amountCol.setCellFactory(param -> new TextEditingCell<>());
    }

    private void setCellValueFactory() {
        idCol.setCellValueFactory(cellData -> cellData.getValue().idProperty());
        qtyCol.setCellValueFactory(cellData -> cellData.getValue().quantityProperty());
        priceUnitCol.setCellValueFactory(cellData -> cellData.getValue().priceUnitProperty());
        discountRateCol.setCellValueFactory(cellData -> cellData.getValue().discountRateProperty());
        discountAmountCol.setCellValueFactory(cellData -> cellData.getValue().discountAmountProperty());
        taxRateCol.setCellValueFactory(cellData -> cellData.getValue().taxRateProperty());
        taxAmountCol.setCellValueFactory(cellData -> cellData.getValue().taxAmountProperty());
        amountCol.setCellValueFactory(cellData -> cellData.getValue().amountProperty());
    }

}
```

**Text Editing Cell**

```javafx
package com.example.testingpurposejavafx;


import javafx.event.Event;
import javafx.scene.control.*;

public class TextEditingCell<S> extends TableCell<S, String> {
    
    protected TextField textField;

    @Override
    public void startEdit() {
        if (isEmpty()) return;
        super.startEdit();
        createTextField();
        setText(null);
        setGraphic(textField);
        textField.requestFocus();
    }


    @Override
    public void cancelEdit() {
        super.cancelEdit();
        setText(getString());
        setGraphic(null);
    }

    @Override
    public void updateItem(String item, boolean empty) {
        super.updateItem(item, empty);
        if (empty) {
            setText(item(item));
            setGraphic(null);
            return;
        }

        if (isEditing()) {
            if (textField != null) {
                textField.setText(item(item));
            }
            setText(null);
            setGraphic(textField);
            return;
        }

        setText(item(item));
        setGraphic(null);
    }

    @Override
    public void commitEdit(String item) {
        if (!isEditing()) {
            TableView<S> table = getTableView();
            if (table != null) {
                TableColumn<S, String> column = getTableColumn();
                TableColumn.CellEditEvent<S, String> event = new TableColumn.CellEditEvent<>(table,
                        new TablePosition<>(table, getIndex(), column),
                        TableColumn.editCommitEvent(), item);
                Event.fireEvent(column, event);
            }
        }
        super.commitEdit(item);
    }

    public void createTextField() {
        this.textField = new TextField();
        textField.setOnAction(e -> commitEdit(textField.getText()));
        textField.focusedProperty().addListener((oV, oldV, newV) -> {
            if (Boolean.FALSE.equals(newV)) commitEdit(textField.getText());
        });
        textField.setText(getString());
    }

    private String getString() {
        return getItem() == null ? "" : getItem() + "";
    }

    public String item(String item) {
        return item == null ? "" : item + "";
    }
}
```

Comment: [mcve] please.. mind the __M__!

Comment: @kleopatra, I have removed the extra code now you can check the question again.

Comment: please read the referenced help page and act accordingly: the minimal example must be runnable as-is and demonstrating the problem - your code doesn't even compile on my machine :) nor does it demonstrate the problem you are describing. Actually I can reproduce the behavior in the cited question (where a way out is to expose the totalPrice as property from the model, thus not requiring an extractor - which might not be possible always) - looks like a bug in selection (there are many, unfortunately)

Comment: beware: your code is doing some stuff that's not well supported (like adding a row, immediately navigating to a new cell and start editing) - so I would expect problems

Comment: But it works perfectly fine without the extractor so I don't think adding a row and doing all those stuff is a problem. Besides for a good user experience, I need those functionalities. Is there any work around for this issue for now

Comment: _I don't think adding a row and doing all those stuff is a problem_ glad it works for you :) But it's unrelated to your problem, so it's unrelated complexity in this context. The problem is: the extractor fires a change of type wasUpdated and table's selectionModel doesn't handle that correctly (it does some default updates leading to the artifact here) .. we probably already have an issue but can't find it right now. That's unrelated to editing, changing a value programmatically has the same effect. Currently, afaik there's no way around except not firing update changes (aka: no extractor)

Comment: thanks for the example :) Though don't quite understand _remove the extractor but then I cannot detect changes in observable list properties_ - which properties? I'm seeing only those exposed by the data class, assuming they are wired internally, there would be no need for the extractor (remember: not using one currently is the only workaround the issue)

Comment: I have labels which need to be updated with the total quantity and total amount in the table rows, by summing them. So every time there is a change in these values of the list I want to detect changes and update those labels.

Comment: Currently, the workaround I am using is to add a listener to these properties in the constructor and update a static property and then attach a listener to this single property instead of exposing the internal properties of the list

Comment: Please trim your code to make it easier to find your problem. Follow these guidelines to create a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).

Comment: thanks for the clarification :) The hack sounds nasty but can't think of anything better, unfortunately. Will file a bug to make sure it gets attention in the next cleanup round of selection (there are .. more issues ;)

Comment: Thanks for the help @kleopatra :) Yes there are many issues in Javafx.